# How do I put a number of char* arrays into a two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino

I have a char array `char *menu_strings[8];` that I fill with the options for an on-screen menu dynamically in a reusable menu() function. I can change the items individually with hand-typed strings, e.g. `menu_strings[0] = "New";` etc. but how do I take a char* returned from another function and insert it into one of the array's "strings"? If I try to loop through the array using the function with something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
  char returnedOption[32];
  if (getOption(i, returnedOption))
    menu_strings[i] = returnedOption;
}

bool getOption(byte entryNum, char* option) {  //code and stuff  }
```

...all 8 menu_strings are filled with the eighth/last option returned (i=7) instead of each individual entry's string...

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++)
  Serial.println(menu_strings[i]);
```

Outputs:

```
option eight
option eight
option eight
option eight
option eight
option eight
option eight
option eight
```

I'm using the arduino IDE but feel pretty confidently that I'd be screwing up the usage of pointers in any C/++/# here. Also, the returned char* is never more than 31 chars plus a null pointer.

Comment: you use `char*` why not string 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String

Comment: `I can change the items individually with hand-typed strings, e.g. menu_strings[0] = "New";` This does not do what you think it does, and that's the problem here. Either use strcpy (but first you'll need malloc, free, etc.) or std::string.

Comment: *but how do I take a char* returned from another function* -- Get out of the `char *` business and simply use `std::string`.  You are also probably returning the address of a local array, given what you posted.  If you are doing that, returning the address of a local variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why not use indexes for the multidimensional part of the array to access the value?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried a strcpy method and got the same result. The getOption() function needs to return a char* because other parts of the program rely on that format, so I'd rather not rewrite everything if I can help it. Can I convert it to a string in the menu() function? If so, how? I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @hoodust You didn't post the code that returns this `char *` you're speaking of.  Again, if you're returning a pointer to a local variable, your code is wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Think I understand, but could it still be the address of a local variable if I get the right data returned in one-offs, but iterating through somehow screws up the previous pulls?

Comment: @hoodust  "Undefined behavior" means just that.  The behavior is undefined.  If you're returning a pointer to a local variable, your code is wrong, regardless of the results you are seeing.  Also, I bet it would be much easier just to change to `std::string` than to fix broken `char *` handling.  The latter may require major rewrites and rethinking (dynamic allocation may have to be used).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well I'm using the u8glib library for all the display handling on arduino, and it expects everything in chars. Would converting the strings to chars for all the display calls be less work and/or make more sense? I don't want to rewrite the graphics library as it's the lightest I've found and firmware size is an issue.

Comment: That is to say, use strings, but then convert them to char for the display functions?

Comment: @hoodust If a third party functions wants a `const char *`, that doesn't mean *your* code has to capitulate and make everything char arrays and pointers.  All you have to do is call the `std::string::c_str()` function for those functions that require a character pointer.

Comment: @yardpenalty Do you mean reference both indices, i.e. menu_strings[0][0]? I tried iterating char by char in an i/j double-for() loop and got the same result, so I think something before that is broken. Quite possibly the local var issue Paul is thinking.

Comment: @hoodust Let's make this easy:  change this `char *menu_strings[8]` to this: `std::string menu_strings[8];`.  Fix the compiler errors, call `c_str()` for those functions from the library you can't change, and you're done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not sure how to use std::string in arduino, but I used their String object [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) as a way to implement your suggestion, and used the arduino toCharArray() [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) to cast the string into something the display library can use with minimal pain, and it works! Thanks so much Paul!

Comment: @hoodust Well, any good string library allows you to do things easily, and should have a function that gives you the `const char *` (or `char *`) that you may need if you're calling a function that you didn't write that happens to need char pointers.  So the Arduino String object is also a viable option (but you should get familiar with `std::string`, as you can use that in practically any C++ platform since -- it's standard).

Comment: Very good point. Thank you again sir!

Comment: Sorry, yes reference both indices

Comment: Ah, I was using strcpy() wrong, which amazes me. This is a much better solution than using the String object in arduino, since it adds around 2k to your program which is about 7% of your usable firmware space on a Pro Micro with a standard bootloader! Using * was just plain incorrect, as you aren't supposed to modify those strings. So thank you to both Paul and @yardpenalty for getting me in the right direction.

Comment: Pointers can be a dangerous game. I only use them when A: I need to worry about memory B: I am iterating through a data structure in RPG or C: I am referencing a variable to edit. I'm sure there are other situations but thats the gist IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to PaulMcKenzie, yardpenalty and deviantfan who led me to the answer:

> Get out of the `char *` business and simply use `std::string`. You are also 
>       probably returning the address of a local array, given what you posted. 
>       If you are doing that, returning the address of a local variable is 
>       undefined behavior.

This led me to use the Arduino String object instead of `char*` https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject
and use `toCharArray()` for any library calls that insist on a char pointer. This works, but added around 2k (or 7% of my usable program memory!).

In the end, I ditched the * pointer as this is incorrect, and used `strcpy` properly as recommended by deviantfan and yardpenalty to stay away from the `String` library. Its liabilities are further extolled here: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/